SFTP login to MacOS 15 fails with "Message too long"
From Centos 8 linux I need to transfer some files to some MacOS machines.
It works from Linux to MacOS 10.13:
sftp danny@Mac10_13_Machine
The authenticity of host '192.168.2.3 (192.168.2.3)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:SRCu/I2rEqFlhy5Y9zdDHVbrAgzPRMG7Z/6tT9S58UA.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.2.3' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Connected to danny@192.168.2.30.

However, trying the same to a machine recently upgraded to 15.0.1 produces a strange error message:
$ sftp danny@Mac_15_Machine
Password:
Received message too long 778199411

I checked with WireShark and there is no huge packet being sent on the network, but because it is encrypted with SSH I can't really debug further.
Any suggestions on how to get the sftp server working properly on MacOS 15?
Indeed, as suggested below, bash on MacOS 15 prints some stuff upon login:
$ ssh danny@xx.xx.xx.xx
Password:
Last login: Wed Oct  9 09:18:06 2024

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

So it is Apple printing the messages on SSH login.  I don't want to switch to zsh. I searched through ~/.bash* and /etc/bash* but didn't find anything that was printing that message.  Anyone know how to disable it?
The output of ssh danny@xx.xx.xx.xx pwd is
$ ssh danny@192.168.2.10 pwd
Password:
.bashrc
/Users/danny


Most likely your startup scripts (like .bashrc) print something that breaks SFTP protocol. You cannot print anything to console in non-interactive session, to avoid breaking protocols like SFTP, SCP, rsync and others.
If you want to print something in interactive (shell) session, use e.g. .bash_profile. I'm sure they correctly do that for the system "The default interactive shell is now zsh" message. So that message won't be the cause of the problem.
My WinSCP FAQ on the same problem:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_large_packet
If you try to connect with WinSCP, it will give you first four characters of the message, so you can identify it easier. Or you can calculate the characters based on the misinterpreted message length from the error message:

Received message too long 778199411

778199411 in hex is 2E-62-61-73. These four positions in ASCII table represent .bas (coming from [as you have found out later] spurious echo .bashrc).
